# Reversible Hashed to convert integer ID to alphabets/alphanumeric

Tags: algorithm, delphi, hash

I need a Delphi *reversible* Hashed ID function that is quick.

- Short, obfuscated and efficient IDs
- No collisions (at least up to 32-bit unsigned integer at least)
- Reversible
- Fast
- preferably something that has an input Key, so it can be randomised a bit...
  otherwise, a '3' will always be 23zkJ5 on all my software modules.
- works cross-platform

Something like Youtube's video identifier.

```
Encode(3); // => "23zkJ5"
Decode('23zkJ5'); // => 3
```

PHP seems to have quite a few of these; I can't find one for Delphi.

I look at this but not really what I wanted, plus I need something in Delphi.

[Reversible hash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273466/)

```php
$generator->encode(6); // => "43Vht7"
$generator->decode('43Vht7'); // => 6
```

I need something like what PHP offers:

https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-IDs

I can't use MD5 as it's not reversible; using Lockbox encryption/decryption seems a bit over-kill? (if really no choice, which algorithm in Lockbox would be the best choice for this?)

Comment: You are not looking for a hash, you are looking for encryption. There are plenty of Delphi source code for that. StackOverflow is not the place to ask recommendation for library or component.

Comment: ok because this php one called it a 'reversible hash'... i tried a couple of encryption but it doesn't stick to alphanumeric characters... base64 after it makes it too long, so I'm just wondering if someone has a quick & simple routine.

Comment: Good old XOR algorithm coupled with some permutations. This is perfectly reversible and easy to implement (and cracked of course).

Comment: If you want to keep to the same character set then look at [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption).  That is a bit more of a hassle to get working, but should do what you want.

Comment: "_but it doesn't stick to alphanumeric characters_" - and so do hashes, so what's your point? If "_reversible hashes_" are possible then you could also tell me if my sum `42` came from the summands `15` and `27` or `-8` and `50`. However, sums can't be reversed to their summands.

Comment: @AmigoJack What i mean is it has non-ascii (?) characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use AES and convert the cypher byte array to a hex string or to Base64.

for a code example see here

[AES encrypt string in Delphi (10 Seattle) with DCrypt, decrypt with PHP/OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285641/aes-encrypt-string-in-delphi-10-seattle-with-dcrypt-decrypt-with-php-openssl/41290878)

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I'm just wondering how some routines can do it with such a short code, eg Youtube is 11 characters long and several PHP routines are even less.  I Just need to cater for 32-bit number (4 billion + numbers).